# Outlook Addin: Tried to remove text from RTFBody using WordEditor

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-word, outlook-addin

I tried to remove an url from the RTFBody of an Outlook.Appointment. I use this code for this:

```
            byte[] rtfBody = myAppointment.RTFBody;
            if (rtfBody.Length > 0)
            {
                if (myAppointment == null)
                {
                    return;
                }
                Outlook.Inspector myInspector = myAppointment.GetInspector;
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document document = myInspector.WordEditor;
                var findObject = document.Application.Selection.Find;
                findObject.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Text = url;
                findObject.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                findObject.Replacement.Text = "";

                object replaceAll = WdReplace.wdReplaceAll;
                findObject.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref replaceAll, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Unfortunately, the code does not replace the URL with the RTFBody. Is there anything missing?
Could it be that some special characters included in the URL like ":", "/" lead to this problem?

After calling Save() on the appointmentitem
it still does not show the replacement

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to call the [Save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.save) method to apply your changes. Only then you may check your results using the RTFBody property or in the Outlook UI.

To make sure the code is working correctly you may run it in a Word add-in to get instant results.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the reason:
If you try (e.g. in Word) to find and replace a text which contains a hyperlink (as a Hyperlink Object in the Word Docment) this will (for some reason NOT Work). 
Therefore I added the following code before the search and replace code (see above):
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Hyperlinks links = document.Hyperlinks;

```
                foreach (Hyperlink link in links)
                {
                    string c = link.TextToDisplay; // perhaps concatenating Address and SubAddress would be better
                    if (c != null)
                    {
                        if (c.Equals(myUrl))
                        {
                            link.Delete();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

To clarify this:
URL contains the whole text block which reads something like this

> "bla bla bla https://something.com/blabla"

whereas myUrl contains

> https://something.com/blabla

Now it works.